# Is it possible to flip table rows easily with the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-word

I use MS word and I have a table with a few rows. I sometimes need to fast-flip the order of two rows, i.e:

bring 
row X
row Y

to be
row Y
row X

Is there a fast keyboard way to do so when I mark both of them with the mouse? Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is one that I know. 
Just position the insertion point at the beginning of the row then hold **Shift** + **Alt** keys together and then just move the rows using the **Up Arrow** or **Down Arrow** keys.